# Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView > 23.3.0 Upgrade issue Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms, android-cardview

I am using Xamarin.Forms and i need to upgrade version of Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView to 23.3.0 but it gives me error.

Using Android 6.0 version to compile the project and API 23 for development.

> Could not install package 'Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView
>   23.3.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'MonoAndroid,Version=v6.0', but the package does not contain
>   any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

Can anyone please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you are only installing the packages that come default when installing `Xamarin Forms`. Otherwise you will not be compatible as `Xamarin Forms` has a hard dependency on the `Support Libraries`.

i.e.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Forms/

```
2.3.0.49

Dependencies:

Xamarin.Android.Support.v4 (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.Design (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)
Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.MediaRouter (= 23.3.0)
```

Although I'm not 100% sure of the way you're trying to update your library, it sounds like you might be on an older version of `Xamarin Forms` and trying to update the one library which the version of `Xamarin Forms` you are on might have a hard dependency on an older version of the `Support Libraries`.

Comment: Hi Jon, yes i am currently using Xamairn 1.5 and i wanted to upgrade it to 2.3.0.49 Latest version and due to "Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.CardView (= 23.3.0)"  dependency i am facing this issue. not sure how to upgrade it to 23.3.0 it gives me error.

Comment: Upgrading your whole project to 2.3.0.49 should resolve this. Ensure that you have the correct <TargetFrameworkVersion> set to the latest API level (In this case 6.0). Remember to only upgrade the Xamarin.Forms package.